# R: Holt Model. Unable to plot timeseries prediction (predict)

Tags: r, time-series, predict

I have been able to use a `lm` `poly`-model to model and predict some timeseries data. However when I change to using a `holt` model, I obtain an error in the R console.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(matrixStats)
library(forecast)

df_input <- read.csv("postprocessed.csv")

x <- df_input$time
y <- df_input$value
df <- data.frame(x, y)

#poly4model <- lm(y~poly(x, degree=4), data=df)
holtmodel <- holt(df$y) # might need df$value here ?
v <- seq(1, 44)
v2 <- seq(44, 55)
    
pdf("postprocessed_holts.pdf")
plot(df, xlim=c(0, 55))
##lines(v, predict(poly4model, data.frame(x=v)), col="blue", pch=20, lwd=3)
##lines(v2, predict(poly4model, data.frame(x=v2)), col="red", pch=20, lwd=3)
lines(v, predict(holtmodel, data.frame(x=v)), col="blue", pch=20, lwd=3)
lines(v2, predict(holtmodel, data.frame(x=v2)), col="red", pch=20, lwd=3)
dev.off()
```

This is the error which shows up

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

I am a bit confused as to what `x` and `y` refer to here. The objects `x` and `y` which are in the Environment (R Studio Environment) both have length 44.

The code appears to error on both lines starting with `lines`.

Here's a copy of the input data...

```
"","time","value"
"1",1,2.61066016308988
"2",2,3.41246054742996
"3",3,3.8608767964033
"4",4,4.28686048552237
"5",5,4.4923132964825
"6",6,4.50557049744317
"7",7,4.50944447661246
"8",8,4.51097373134893
"9",9,4.48788748823809
"10",10,4.34603985656981
"11",11,4.28677073671406
"12",12,4.20065901625172
"13",13,4.02514194962519
"14",14,3.91360194972916
"15",15,3.85865748409081
"16",16,3.81318053258601
"17",17,3.70380706527433
"18",18,3.61552922363713
"19",19,3.61405310598722
"20",20,3.64591327503384
"21",21,3.70234435835577
"22",22,3.73503970503372
"23",23,3.81003078640584
"24",24,3.88201196162666
"25",25,3.89872518158949
"26",26,3.97432743542362
"27",27,4.2523675144599
"28",28,4.34654855854847
"29",29,4.49276038902684
"30",30,4.67830892029687
"31",31,4.91896819673664
"32",32,5.04350767355202
"33",33,5.09073406942046
"34",34,5.18510849382162
"35",35,5.18353176529036
"36",36,5.2210776270173
"37",37,5.22643491929207
"38",38,5.11137006553725
"39",39,5.01052467981257
"40",40,5.0361056705898
"41",41,5.18149486951409
"42",42,5.36334869132276
"43",43,5.43053620818444
"44",44,5.60001072279525
```

#### Edit

I tried an alternative method as well. I noticed that the object `holtmodel` contains two objects which might be useful. They are `fitted` and `mean`. As far as I can tell this is the fitted timeseries and the mean timeseries for the next 10 steps/predictions.

I tried plotting these objects with

```
lines(holtmodel$fitted, col="orange", lwd=2)
lines(holtmodel$mean, col="blue", lwd=2)
```

however the second of these fails to plot anything, despite no error being produced in the console. The first line plots an orange timeseries as expected.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are trying to display. Are you trying to have the line in blue (with predict on v) to follow the original data and the line in red to be a prediction of the upcoming values ?

Comment: @PierreChevallier Yes, the blue part should be the fitted model, which has been fitted to all the datapoints (which are in the range of 1..44) and the red part should be a prediction 10 steps into the future.

Answer (score 1):

## Your issue

The objects you are trying to add as lines don't have the same length:

```
length(predict(holtmodel, data.frame(x=v)))
# 10
length(v)
# 44
length(predict(holtmodel, data.frame(x=v2)))
# 10
length(v2)
# 12
```

This means you can't add them as new lines.

Also, you can't really predict the same way you would with a linear regression by using say, older data as point to prepare the model. [Exponential smoothing methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) use historical data points to build future data points, you can't really display them for past events.

Also, you are not specifying the parameter for the number of periods you are trying to predict (`h`), I'll let you refer to the [documentation on the holt function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.14/topics/ses). It is already a prediction of future events that is the output, so the use of `predict()` on it doesn't change the result:

```
holt_predict <- predict(holtmodel)
length(setdiff(holt_predict, holtmodel))
# 0 which means they are the same objects
```

## Solution

What you could do is use directly mean and fitted and plot them with lines, by also expanding the area to plot the chat with `xlim` and `ylim` to view the predicted values. You can directly plot `holtmodel$fitted` and `holtmodel$mean` on your chart, since they are time series objects:

```
plot(df, xlim=c(0, 60), ylim=c(2.5, 10))
lines(holtmodel$fitted, col="blue", pch=20, lwd=3)
lines(holtmodel$mean, col="red", pch=20, lwd=3)
```

And the result:

[image]

## Easy alternative

To save you the hassle of having to go through this kind of solution there are easier methods. Have you tried the `autoplot` function included in the package `forecast` ? It is from ggplot2 and will give you what you want directly (unless you don't want the confidence intervals). It is very straightforward and will probably yield results close to what you want:

```
autoplot(holtmodel)
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks, lots of useful information here. Let me just address the first points. If the length of v is 44, then why is the output of the prediction with "x=v" an object of length 10? That seems strange? All I'm trying to plot is the smoothed function, aka "the Holts function of the timeseries data"

Comment: c.f. my edit (after refreshing the page) where you can plot the fitted function. But simply, the `holt` function gives you already the fitted values of length 44, the predict function will always return a length 10 which corresponds to the length of the object elements (you can check what's inside with `str(holtmodel)`. You can't use the output of `holt()` with predict.

Comment: Ah yes, expanding the axis range, that certainly solves one problem

Comment: Hmm, the autoplot command isn't producing any output. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: That is strange, event after creating holtmodel ? I ran your example above to get the autoplot attached. I wonder what is the issue, maybe with your additional data ?

Comment: Yes it works from with R but not R Studio?

Comment: This sounds strange, I don't have this issue and the plot above it produced from RStudio too